# Service Fabric Containers - Cannot Access Service within Cluster

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a Windows Container deployed locally on my development VM that just contains a simple MVC app to test functionality. I can deploy it fine and I get the Uri for the service at http://localhost:30001/ which works fine when I navigate to that URL from my host but I cannot access it when I'm within my VM that has the container.

`Laptop (Can access URL from here)`

^

`Windows Server 2016 VM (cannot access from here)`

^

`Container with manually packaged MVC app using the microsoft/aspnet image`

After I've deployed the SF application I can access the MVC app via the assigned ip and port from Docker (via using `docker inspect`) also, I've specified that port `8745` within my `AppManifest.xml`

When I spin up one of the example applications such as the Alphabet example I'm able to access the endpoint within the VM. Is there something to do with Containers that doesn't allow this? This is a big problem when making a Gateway Stateless service as the partition resolver give me the URL that isn't accessible within the cluster.

EDIT: 
Forgot to mention that my firewall is also disabled inside my development VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're hitting [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/05/25/windows-nat-winnat-capabilities-and-limitations/) issue. You can't access containers running on localhost unless you use the Container ip address.

> With the current release, you can't use http://localhost to browse
>   your site from the container host. This is because of a known behavior
>   in WinNAT, and will be resolved in future. Until that is addressed,
>   you need to use the IP address of the container.

Comment: that's odd.. Service Fabric publishes the endpoint as `http://localhost:30001`. Does that mean I cannot have service to service communication with containers? Or is there some way of getting that containers IP address via the naming service?

Comment: On a production cluster, you can communicate between containers using the reverse proxy. That way your traffic flows through the load balancer. (Not ideal.)   More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container I don't think you can get this to work on a dev cluster, without WinNAT being fixed.

Comment: Anybody know if there's an update on this yet? I'm still having issues accessing my container in service fabric from localhost

Comment: It should be fixed in the coming 1803 release.

Comment: It's not fixed in 1809.